# Associated graded ring of an ideal is reduced, then the ideal is normal.

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals, graded-rings

> Let $I$ be an ideal in a Noetherian ring $R$ such that $\mathrm{gr}_I(R)$ is a reduced ring. Prove that $I$ is normal.

What is the error in this proof?

We proceed by induction over $n$.

If $n=1$ we show that $\overline{I} \subseteq I$. Let $r$ be an element in $\overline{I}$. We have that $\overline{I} \subseteq \sqrt{I}$, thus there exists $l$ such that $r^l \in I$. Then, $([r]_0)^l=[r^l]_0=0$. As  $\mathrm{gr}_I(R)$ is a reduced ring, then $[r]_0=0$. Therefore, $r \in I$.

For $n>1$, we show that $\overline{I^n} \subseteq I^n$. We know that $I^n \subseteq \overline{I^n}$ is a reduction. Hence, there exists $l$ such that $\overline{I^n}^{l+1}=I^n\overline{I^n}^l$. Then, $$\overline{I^n}^{l+1}\subseteq I^n\overline{I^{n-1}}^l=I^n(I^{n-1})^l=I^{l(n-1)+n}$$ by inductive hypothesis. Hence, for every $r\in \overline{I^n}$, $r^{l+1} \in I^{l(n-1)+n}$. Thus, $([r]_{n-1})^{l+1}=[r^{l+1}]_{(l+1)(n-1)}=[r^{l+1}]_{l(n-1)+n-1}=0$.  As  $\mathrm{gr}_I(R)$ is a reduced ring, then $[r]_{n-1}=0$. Therefore, $r \in I^n$.

Comment: Every ideal is a reduction of its closure. And by definition $J \subseteq I$ is a reduction if there exists $l$ such that $I^{l+1}=JI^l$

Comment: How do you know there is an error in the proof?

Comment: The only change I'd make is to consider $[r]_k$ with $r\in I^k\setminus I^{k+1}$ instead of $[r]_{n-1}$. The rest looks ok to me.

Comment: This proof was made by my, another mathematician told me that it has an error. But, he did not tell me where is.

Comment: I talked with the professor who told me that this proof is incorrect. He read again it and he told me that there is no error. He was wrong.